# How to mix multiple domain objects in a single form?

Tags: data-binding, grails, groovy, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have 3 domains :
- EligibilityInclusion
- EligibilityExclusion
- EligibilitySummary

I build also eligibility.gsp (mix use of 3 templates : _inclusion, _exclusion, _summary ; and I'm also using JQueryUI tab to render each domain in one tab).

Everything fine for viewing, but now I would like to use only one controller to create, edit, list and show.
How can I handle 3 domains via only one controller?
(for example, I would like to use EligibilityController to handle my 3 domains)

What is the best usage:
- binding multiple objets?
- use command objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately command objects don't help with the input model for a view, they are specifically designed to aide the output model for the binding and validation of request parameters.  However you can roll your own View Model based on a command object if you are prepared to delve into some meta programming to to achieve the data binding for the creation of the view model.
Here's a basic approach.  The following code constructs the Command Object which you can then pass as the model to the view in the controller:

```
class ItemCommand {
 // attribute declarations ...

public void bindData(def domainInstance){
    domainInstance.properties.keySet().each { prop ->
        if(prop == "class"){
            // not needed
        } else if(prop == "metaClass") {
            // not needed
        } else if(this.properties.containsKey(prop)){
            this."${prop}" = domainInstance."${prop}"
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to bind the data from different domain objects by calling bindData for each of the domain objects.

This is the essence of the solution I use. You will need to store the ids of the different domain objects (and the version attribute) as hidden fields if you intend to do updates to the domain objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just submit multiple objects, if some of them have same field names, right?

I'd try to join the 3 objects into single Command with 3 fields, like: `inclusionInstance1, inclusingInstance2, summaryInstance1`, and name fields in gsp-s respectively, like `name='command.inclusionInstance1.name'`. Assigning `command.properties = params` should work when submitting the form.